# Wrong output in some tests

Tags: java, string, math

I have troubles in one method. In input we have string, for example (a+-b*i)some sign(c+-d*i). Program must calculate this and output result. I need to take index of sign in the first bracket and index in the second bracket. And than my program will be working. But, when in input (a-b*i)-(c-d*i) or (a-b*i)*(c-d*i) only, method returning wrong result -1.

My methods for two brackets.

```
public int getSign1(String str)
    {
        int sign1;
        if(str.indexOf("+") < str.indexOf(")")) 
            sign1 = str.indexOf("+"); 
        else if(str.indexOf("-", 2) < str.indexOf(")")) 
            sign1 = str.indexOf("-", 2);
        else sign1 = -1; 

        return sign1;
    }

    public int getSign2(String str)
    {
        int sign2;
        if(str.lastIndexOf("+") > str.lastIndexOf("(")) 
            sign2 = str.lastIndexOf("+");
        else if(str.lastIndexOf("-") > str.lastIndexOf("(")) 
            sign2 = str.lastIndexOf("-");
        else sign2 = -1;

        return sign2;
    }
```

The second method always working, but not the first (Please help me to find error).

Example: `(1-2i)*(3-4i)`

The first method is returning -1, but not 2. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in the expression:

`(1-2i)*(3-4i)` you don't have any `+` char, and after seeing [String#lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29):

> the index of the last occurrence of the character in the character
>   sequence represented by this object, **or -1 if the character does not
>   occur**.

Then you know why `str.lastIndexOf("+")` will be -1. And it's of course <  `str.indexOf(")")`.

So `sign1` will be -1.

You can fix it by:

```
if(str.indexOf("+")!= -1 && str.indexOf("+") < str.indexOf(")"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I forget about it

Answer (score 1):

For input `(a-b*i)-(c-d*i)` , here there is no '+' in this string.

```
public int getSign1(String str){
     if(str.indexOf("+") < str.indexOf(")")) 
                sign1 = str.indexOf("+");
..
}
```

In this method first if you are checking '+' , hence it is not there its index is -1 which is less than  `str.indexOf(")")` index so its returing `-1`.